# What is the value of $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (p-1)^2\pmod{p}$?

Tags: number-theory

What is the value of $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (p-1)^2\pmod{p}$?

Let's try a several primes greater than 3...

If $p=5$, then we have $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 = 30$, so that $30\pmod{5} = 0$

If $p=7$, then we have $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2= 91$, so that $91\pmod{7} = 0$

If $p=11$, then we have $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2 + 7^2 + 8^2 + 9^2 + 10^2= 385$, so that $385\pmod{11} = 0$

So it seems like we will always get 0. So for primes greater than 3, we have the sum equal to a multiple of $p$.

I know that $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (p-1)^2 = \frac16p(p-1)(2p-1)$.Well if $p>3$, then $p-1=2a$ for some integer $a$, so that $2p-1 = 4a +1$. Then we have 
$$ 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (p-1)^2 = \frac16p(p-1)(2p-1) = \frac16 p(2a)(4a+1)$$

If I could show that $(2a)(4a+1)$ is a multiple of 6, I'll be done, but I am having trouble showing that. Perhaps someone could provide a much needed tip, but **don't figure this out for me, please.**

Comment: Observe that the sum of squares of integers is always an integer, and $(p,6)=1$ for all primes $p\gt 3$, therefore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You don't need $a$: consider separately the cases $p\equiv1\pmod3$ and $p\equiv2\pmod3$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the formula for sum of squares (which has to be an integer) we see that  the 6 in the denominator has to divide the numerator: Now 6 is coprime to $p$ (for $p >3$). Now you can figure it out yourself.